# How do I prevent a color from repeating in a Collection View Cell in Swift?

Tags: swift, class

My code has a bug that is repeating ProgressBar foregroundColor every 6 cells.

From my research, I think that it is repeating because I am trying to configure it in the `dequeueReusableCell` function.

I have a custom class for a progress ring:

```
import UIKit

class ProgressBar: UIView {
    
    public var backgroundCircleColor: CGColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    public var foregroundCircleColor: CGColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    
    private var backgroundLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    private var foregroundLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height
        let lineWidth = 0.1 * min(width, height)
        
        backgroundLayer = createCircularLayer(rect: rect, strokeColor: backgroundCircleColor, fillColor: UIColor.clear.cgColor, lineWidth: lineWidth)
        foregroundLayer = createCircularLayer(rect: rect, strokeColor: foregroundCircleColor, fillColor: UIColor.clear.cgColor, lineWidth: lineWidth)
    
        layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(foregroundLayer)
        
    }
    
    private func createCircularLayer(rect: CGRect, strokeColor: CGColor, fillColor: CGColor, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {
        
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height
        let lineWidth = 0.1 * min(width, height)
        let center = CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height / 2)
        let radius = (min(width, height) / 2.5)
        let startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
        let endAngle = startAngle + CGFloat.pi * 2
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
      
        return shapeLayer
        
    }
    
}
```

Here is the ViewController:

`cell.foregroundCircleColor` is repeating every 6 cells.
`cell.layer.shadowColor` works perfectly.

```
import UIKit

class BudgetVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

extension BudgetVC: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return categories.count

    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BudgetCell", for: indexPath) as! BudgetCell
        
        cell.nameLabel.text = categories[indexPath.item].name
        
        cell.progressRingView.foregroundCircleColor = categories[indexPath.item].color.cgColor

        cell.layer.shadowColor = categories[indexPath.item].color.cgColor
            
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

And here is my CollectionViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class BudgetCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressRingView: ProgressBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountSpentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountBudgetedLabel: UILabel!

    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
 }
    
    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        
        configureCell()

    }
    
}

extension UICollectionViewCell {
    func configureCell() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        
    }
}
```

I feel like I need to configure the ProgressBar attributes in the CollectionViewCell `override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)` but I don't know how to relate it to `indexPath.item`.

Should I make ProgressBar an extension instead of a class?

Could you show me an example of some code that might work?

I'm quite new to Swift and programming, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It all has to do with the fact that your ProgressBar object is incorrectly written. It may *look* like it's working for the first six rows, but it isn't really.

First, merely setting your ProgressBar object's `foregroundCircleColor` does not cause anything else to happen. You are setting a property, but the ProgressBar does not respond to that by changing its appearance.

You need to put a setter observer on the `foregroundCircleColor` property so that when it is set, you mark the ProgressBar as needing to be redrawn. (It's just chance that for the first six rows, `draw` was being called after you set the property.)

A second issue is that you are implementing `draw` all wrong. In `draw` you should never do anything but draw. What you are doing is adding sublayers. That's wrong. Not only that, but since `draw` can be called many times over the life of the view, you will be piling sublayers on top of one another, because you keep adding them but you never remove the old ones.